# Unicode characters stored in session doing strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, unicode

We are storing user name in SESSION during login. When we are fetching it in another page, the **unicode** texts like ***Russion*** text converted to ***?????***.

Is there any setting need to do ? Using IIS 6

Comment: I have tried by adding below setting, but still it does not work :( <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8"  responseEncoding="utf-8"/>    Any expert advice.